# How to show grouped data and button controls in something like DataGrid?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid

I have to show a expandable table that also has buttons and looks like the below. I'm thinking of using DataGrid but I'm not sure how to go about doing so. I'm also using Winforms.

```
+ ServiceName | Route: /api/sth
  + Input Parameters
      Class| <Button> Add default value </Button>
      Major| <Button> Add default value </Button>
  + Output Parameters
      Name | <Checkbox> Hide from user </CheckBox> | Old name
      Phone| <Checkbox> Hide from user </CheckBox> | Old phone

- ServiceName | Route: /api/sthelse
```

and so on. How would I do so in Winforms(edit: Or WPF)? The data is loaded from a list of Service Objects.

Service:

```
List<string> inparams;
List<string> outparams;
string servicename;
string route;
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This is not something a `DataGridView` is meant for. Have you considered using a `TreeView`?

Comment: I tried but TreeView does not support multiple columns and it seemed more hacky that way.

Comment: You searching for hierarchical datagridview, .NET datagridview control doesn't support hierarchical data. You can check some winfroms hierarchical controls of third part. Or you can use WPF `ListView` or `DataGrid` controls inside winforms